# Saving variable of unknown subclass type in switch statement

Tags: java, inheritance, scope, subclass, superclass

I have a superclass TetrisPiece, with subclasses for each variation of the piece, i.e.

```
class PieceI extends TetrisPiece{
}

class PieceJ extends TetrisPiece{
}

etc...
```

In a different class I have a switch statement based on a random number that creates a random piece

```
switch(rand){
      //I
      case 1: {
       PieceI pieceI = new PieceI();
       break;
      }
      //T
      case 2: {
       PieceT pieceT = new PieceT();
       break;
      }
      etc...
      default:
       break;
}
```

My intention is to extract the piece that is generated from the scope of the switch statement so I can use it later on in the class.

The switch method obviously does not work because of the scope issue, and I cannot create a superclass array outside of the switch statement because I would have no ability to cast the indices due to randomization.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: **How** do you intend to use it later on? `TetrisPiece piece;` and then you can assign `PieceI` or `PieceJ` instances to `piece`.

Comment: The best way is for PieceI and PieceJ to share a common interface.

Comment: replace your switch statement with polymorphism

Comment: ElliottFrisch that's the issue is I won't know how to assign them due to a random subclass being used.
@haifzhan could you explain a bit more in depth please

Comment: @ElliottFrisch that doesn't seem to work. I try to access the methods or instance variables of the subclass but I am only allowed to access the superclass

Comment: As ScaryWombat said, **program to a *common* interface**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an instance of the superclass TetrisPiece, and then assign PieceT, PieceI, etc to it inside the switch statement.

```
TetrisPiece piece;

switch(rand){
  //I
  case 1: {
   piece = new PieceI();
   break;
  }
  //T
  case 2: {
   piece = new PieceT();
   break;
  }
  etc...
  default:
   break;
}
```

Comment: The issue is I can't access the methods or instance variables of the subclass that I assign to piece

Comment: Do your piece types have different methods and variables than the superclass TetrisPiece? If so you should follow a more strict polymorphism design. TetrisPiece should ideally be an interface that the pieces implement. I'm assuming the main thing that needs to be different between the pieces is rotating them, so in your interface you'd have a rotate method that the pieces would override.

Comment: That is a very good suggestion. Last question in that case. If were to have the rotate methods overriden in each subclass, and I do not explicitly cast "piece", the choice of override method is automatically determined by which subclass I assigned to "piece", correct?

Comment: Yeah. Basically your subclasses should not have any methods of variables that your superclass doesn't. It's a little bit different way of thinking. So for instance, each piece is going to have a rotate left and rotate right method. In your TetrisPiece superclass, you'd have a method called like public void rotateRight(), which will likely have no code in it. Then in your subclass, you write the same method with the piece specific code, and when you reference that with the code in the answer, it will use the method from the subclass and not the superclass.

Comment: Awesome. And for instance variables, just use overriden getter and setter methods? (Since I can't override the variables themselves)

Comment: Yes you can override getters and setters as well. If you want some more information on inheritance and polymorphism, read through some of this documentation from Oracle. It has some good explanations and code examples of how to use interfaces, overriding methods, etc. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/index.html